# SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (igdkmd64.sys)

Tags: windows-10, bsod, intel-graphics

I try to install newest Intel HD Graphics 4600 drivers on Windows 10, but get the BSOD: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (igdkmd64.sys). I tried drivers from:

- Intel site
- Asus (Motherboard manufacturer) site
- Windows Update

This error come every time when trying to update the drivers. The Device Manager shows Microsoft generic VGA graphics adapter drivers and Intel drivers cannot be installed. The BSOD comes either while installing or after reboot.

The system has only Intel's onboard graphics.

How could I get Intel drivers installed without BSOD?

[image: BSOD]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution and want to share it. My system is now working with newest Intel drivers installed via Windows Update. No BSOD so far.

I uninstalled **the Lucidlogix Virtu MVP GPU Virtualization software** and after that the GPU driver of Intel installed successfully.

The helpful post was found from http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/37892-bsod-boot-system_service_exception-error.html:

> Although the crash dump blames igdkmd64.sys (Intel HD Graphics Driver)
>   as the reason behind the crashes, it is no the real culprit here. It
>   seems that the Lucidlogix Virtu MVP GPU Virtualization software which
>   is playing the villein role here.
>
> Code:

```
ffffd000`22576760  fffff800`01e12b20Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\VirtuWDDM.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for VirtuWDDM.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for VirtuWDDM.sys
 VirtuWDDM+0x1b20
ffffd000`22576768  fffff800`01e12b84 VirtuWDDM+0x1b84
ffffd000`22576770  fffff800`01e12bd8 VirtuWDDM+0x1bd8
ffffd000`22576778  fffff800`01e12c2c VirtuWDDM+0x1c2c
ffffd000`22576780  fffff800`01e12cf0 VirtuWDDM+0x1cf0
```

> I have seen similar issues created by this software before (even two
>   days before). Please uninstall all the components of this crapware
>   from the system and your issue will be solved.

Comment: I searched for Lucidlogix Virtu MVP GPU Virtualization software on my computer but couldn't find it. Instead, I updated the driver and it worked just fine (see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/1132955/windows-10-lenovo-pc-ran-into-a-blue-screen-and-need-restart-failed-on-igdkmd64/1170108#1170108)).