# Windows 10 Lenovo pc ran into a blue screen and need restart failed on igdkmd64 sys

Tags: windows-10, bsod, operating-systems

Problem with blue screen on Windows 10 pc/ I am receiving this in Windows 10 multiple times a day. It used to be once in a week. Recently it's occurring multiple time a day. I have raised this issue with Microsoft

[image]
[image]

Any one have same issue? Is there a software patch or any drivers that may cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`igdkmd64.sys` is the Intel HD graphic driver. Go to [Intel and downlod the latest driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD%20Graphics) for your Intel HD chip.

Comment: does the new driver fix the crashes?

Comment: ok, mark the question as answered: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your driver. To do this, install [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_iduu) and then run the program. When you run the program, press the <kbd>Start Scan</kbd> button in the window. Then it will take a little while for the program to search for drivers. When it's done with that, a <kbd>Download</kbd> button will appear on the bottom right. Click on it, follow all the steps in the assistant and then let it update the driver. When it's done updating the driver, restart your computer and the problem is fixed.